# Cummulative SUM Measure in DAX is not working

Tags: powerbi, data-science, dax, data-analysis, data-manipulation

I'm a novice at DAX language, and I'm attempting to create a measure which displays the accumulative sum of records by day; problem is, instead of showing the sum of each record, I see the same results of the column ID, which is the one i'm using ot calculate it (meaning: nothing changes :)

```
ID_Cum_IF = 
var vMaxDate = CALCULATE(Max([DATA_Subscription]), ALL(Calendar[Date]))
//This Calendar date is an aux table with the dates same as from my original table

var vDateToday = MAX(Calendar[Date]

var RESULT = 
IF(
        vDateToday <= vDataMaxDate,

    CALCULATE(
        [Value_Acum_sum], 
        FILTER(ALL(Calendar), Calendar[Date] <= vDateToday)
    ),[Value_Acum_sum]
)

RETURN RESULT
```

So the result I'm expecting is, in the last column, instead of seeing the same numbers as of the other measure I created (Total Count/Day) or the ID column, I need to see
1 in the first line
3 in the second line
8 in the third.....

[Table I'm using to see if what I'm doing is working x aux table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1t8PI.png)

Any ideas of what's wrong with my code?
I made it using some online tutorials, tweaked it a little bit, but I think something is missing here.

Thanks for the experts for the help with this! :D

Comment: What is your data look like? Can you include a sample? Also what is `[DATA_Subscription]` and `[Value_Acum_sum]`?

Comment: Seems, it always true  `vDateToday <= vDataMaxDate`.

Comment: This `vMaxDate` also can be filtered by month filter or other. So, check if the date is correct.

Comment: check your dates vDateToday  and vDateToday , add them to the matrix as measure. If they are correct for each row. Then add more info - a measure code and columns in used tabels.

Comment: @TalitaNieps Your DAX logic is problematic from the start. Ensure that you get the data from the right columns of the right tables. For example your 2nd var definition should get the value from the column of fact table, not the date column of date table. You also want to get cumulative total; but you are using wrong structure. You should use ''TotalYTD" Function or (Calculate & DATESYTD) combination together to achieve your goal. Please work on it a little more. Please keep in mind that If your model sucks, even the best DAX code can't save you.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your inputs - I managed to fix the logic, so I got it right, thanks to your comments! :D
Thanks a lot!!